# Large buttons in appcelerator

Tags: iphone, ios5, titanium-mobile, appcelerator-mobile

I have created an app in Titanium Appcelerator. The app worked fine up until the iPhone 5 came out and ios 6. The issue is in the button bar the buttons are larger than they should be. They overlap the bar.

Here is an image as well as the code for the button. Has anyone ran into this issue before?

http://postimage.org/image/thlu3i8pf/

```
    var statusButton = Titanium.UI.createButtonBar({
    labels:['Open', 'Closed'],
    backgroundColor:'#336699'
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you're using Titanium SDK 2.1.4 or newer -- 2.1.3 & 2.1.4 contain a number of fixes for iOS 6 and iPhone 5.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add height.

```
var statusButton = Titanium.UI.createButtonBar({
labels:['Open', 'Closed'],
backgroundColor:'#336699',
height: 40
});
```